# Change scroll interval/unit/pixels

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way to change the size of each scroll with php code.
Explanation: When I scroll down it goes down x (50~) pixels, I wanna change the x to 20.

**EDIT:** This is my code...

```
<html>
  <head><link rel="icon" href="Images/Excel.png"><title>Excel</title></head>
  <body bgcolor="9EB6CE" style="margin:0;width:3354"><?php
    print"<input src='Images\\0.png' type='image'>";
    $i=1;
    while($i<=26){
      print"<input src='Images\\".chr(64+$i).".png' type='image'>";
      $i++;
    }
    $i=1;
    while($i<=26){
      print"<input src='Images\\A".chr(64+$i).".png' type='image'>";
      $i++;
    }
    $i=1;
    $j=1;
    while($i<=100){
      print "<input src='Images\\".$i.".png' type='image'>";
      while($j<=52){
        print"<input src='Images\\Cell.png' type='image'>";
        $j++;
      }
      $j=1;
      $i++;
    }
  ?></body>
</html>
```